# Создание Instance для доступа c#

Tags: c#

Доброго времени суток.

В своих проектах использую конструкцию для доступа к MainWindow из других классов. И вот задался вопросом насколько это правильно и безопасно использовать. Если не безопасно, то если способы обезопасить?

Видел много аналогов этому, ни все они не такие простые и удобные.

```
 public static MainWindow Instance;

 public MainWindow()
 {
    InitializeComponent();
    Instance = this;
 }

 MainWindow.Instance.List.ItemsSource = null;
```

Comment: А зачем делать глобальный объект, если можно просто передать его параметром при необходимости?

Comment: Если вопрос в том, правильно ли это - нет, не правильно. Безопасно ли это в отношении чего? Статическое поле само по себе ваше приложение не положит

Comment: В большинстве случаев использую если нужно передавать постоянно меняющиеся значение по типу таймера, который находится в классе. Для того, что бы не использовать PropertyChanged

Comment: чтобы что то куда то передавать статические поля не нужны. Вы можете в вашем DI контейнере зарегать сервис и испольщовать его для передачи чего угодно куда угодно. Если это чтото типа событий, то есть агрегаторы событий для приложений, которые для этого и презназначены. То есть статика для этого не нужна, а роль синглтона можно настроить для любого сервиса через DI контейнер

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поскольку главное окно в приложении по определению одно, использовать синглтон для него нормально. Но делать это нужно правильно. Не используйте публичное поле (его можно случайно изменить в любом месте программы), вместо этого заверните его в get-only свойство:

```
static MainWindow _Instance = null;

public static MainWindow Instance
{
     get { return this._Instance;}
}
```

Также необходимо сделать защиту от повторного создания объекта (если код написан в предположении, что существует только один объект, случайное повторное его создание может все сломать). Сделать конструктор закрытым скорее всего не получится, так как отвалится дизайнер форм, но можно проверять, что окно уже создано, и бросать исключение.